# Hearing impaired and iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, ringtones, vibrate

A friend of me got a new iPhone 13, but is now disappointed from the sound of the iPhone. The ringtone isn't loud enough as well as the vibration is too subtle.

Are there any settings/tricks which could help with this?

Loudness is on max. level and flash light setting is on. But that isn't enough ... Don't know if special ringtones could improve this and imho Apple should provide such ones.

Are there special third party devices, which could help with this? I don't mean a new hearing aid device, but e.g. a bluetooth loudspeaker which runs all the time and can increase the sound if a call comes in. I know the [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210070) from Apple, but that isn't helping me exactly in this case. Is there a cheaper option than buying an Apple Watch?